# $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly in an interval

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Let $f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a sequence of functions and $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Which of the following statements are correct?

(a) If $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly in each interval of the form $(a, +\infty)$, then $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly in the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

(b) If for each $a>0$ it holds that $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly in $(a, +\infty)$, then $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly in $[0,+\infty)$.

(c) If $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly in each closed and bounded interval, then $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly in the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

(d) If $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly in the whole $\mathbb{R}$ and $f_n$ are continuous, then $f$ can be continuous.

$$$$

At uniform convergence the properties of $f_n$ hold also for $f$. So since $f_n$ are continuous, then $f$ must be also continuous. So (d) doesn't hold because $f$ **is** continuous, right?

At (a) and (c) we have to check if the union of the respective intervals is equal to $\mathbb{R}$, right?

At (b) we have to check if $\bigcup_a (a,  +\infty)=[0,\infty)$, right?

Comment: Your attempt using unions will not work, because for example $\mathbb{R}$ is not the union of a finite number of intervals of the form $(a,+\infty)$. Given that there is an $N_a$ for which $n \geqslant N_a, \, x \in (a,+\infty) \implies |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ then it is not always possible to find an upper bound $\sup_a N_a$ which demonstrates uniform convergence on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

It is not difficult to find counterexamples that show that (a), (b), and (c) are false.

For (c) consider the sequence $f_n(x) = \frac{x}{n}$ which converges pointwise to $f(x) = 0$.  On any closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$  we have

$$\left|f_n(x) - f(x) \right| = \left| \frac{x}{n}\right| \leqslant \frac{\max(a,b)}{n}$$

For any $\epsilon > 0$ take $N(\epsilon)  \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N(\epsilon) > \max(a,b)/\epsilon$. For all $n \geqslant N(\epsilon)$ and for all $x \in [a,b]$ we have

$$|f_n(x) - f(x)|\leqslant \frac{\max(a,b)}{n} \leqslant \frac{\max(a,b)}{N(\epsilon)} \leqslant \epsilon,$$

and, thus, $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$.  However, the convergence is not  uniform on $\mathbb{R}$, since

$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\left| f_n(x) - f(0) \right| = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\left| \frac{x}{n} \right| = +\infty \underset{n \to \infty}{\not\to}0$$

A counterexample for (b) is $f_n(x) = \begin{cases}(1-x)^n,&0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1\\ 0, & x > 1 \end{cases}$. Try yourself to understand this and also find a counterexample for (a).

Comment: As for (b) : We consider an interval $(a,+\infty)$. The sequence $f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to $f(x)=0$, right? Then we have that $$\sup_{x\in [a,+\infty)}|f_n-f(x)|\leq \sup_{x\in [a,+\infty)}|1-x|^n\rightarrow 0$$ and so we have uniform convergence in $[a,+\infty)$, right? But $$\sup_{x\in [0,+\infty)}|f_n-f(x)|\leq \sup_{x\in [0,+\infty)}|1-x|^n=1\not\rightarrow 0$$and so we don't have uniform convergence in $[0,+\infty)$. Is that correct?

Comment: Doesn't (a) follow because of (b) ?

Comment: Your argument for (b) is correct.  Now (a) doesn’t follow from (b) because (a) has a stronger hypothesis where there is uniform convergence on intervals containing $0$.  You could modify the counterexample I gave for (c) where $f_n(x) = |x|/n$ for $x <0$.

Comment: At (a) considering the sequence $f_n(x) = \frac{|x|}{n}$ which converges pointwise to $f(x) = 0$, we have on any interval $(a,+\infty)$  that
$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\left| f_n(x) - f(0) \right| = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\left| \frac{x}{n} \right| = +\infty \underset{n \to \infty}{\not\to}0$$ so we don't have uniform convergence, or have I understood that wrong?

Comment: @MaryStar: I meant $f_n(x) = |x|/n$ for $x < 0$ and $f_n(x) = 0$ for $x \geqslant 0$. That converges pointwise to $0$ obviously but $f_n(x_n) \not\to 0$ for $x_n = -n$.

Comment: To show that $f_n$ converges uniformly at an interval $(a,+\infty)$ do we have to take cases as for the sign of $a$ ? I mean : If $a<0$ then $$\sup_{x\in (a,+\infty)}|f_n(x)|=\sup_{x\in (a,0)}\frac{|x|}{n}=\frac{a}{n}\rightarrow 0$$ If $a\geq 0$ then $$\sup_{x\in (a,+\infty)}|f_n(x)|=\sup_{x\in [0,+\infty)}0=0\rightarrow 0$$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar: That works.  More concisely, $\sup_{x\in (a,+\infty)}|f_n(x)|= \max(\sup_{x\in (a,0)}|f_n(x)|, \sup_{x\in [0,\infty))}|f_n(x)|) = \max(|a|/n,0) \to 0$.

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you!! A question... At statement (d) if we had "If $f_n\to f$ uniformly in the whole $\mathbb{R}$ and $f_n$ are not continuous, then $f$ can be continuous." would it be correct?

Comment: @MaryStar:  We can have $f_n \to f$ uniformly with all $f_n$ discontinuous and where $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Why do you think (d) is not a true statement?  By the uniform limit theorem, $f$ must be continuous, so it is not  false to say it can be continuous.  It just can't be discontinuous.  Similarly, if $f_n \to f$ uniformly and each $f_n$ is discontinuous it is true that $f$ can be continuous$.